# Configure hosts in Debian and Apache Multisite

Tags: php, apache, debian, virtualhost, hosts

I'm trying to configure Debian Jessie 8 VPS with Apache & PHP-FPM to serve multisite.

This is my `/etc/hosts` file.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 subdomain.mysite.com
127.0.1.1 site1.com
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Where subdomain.mysite.com is my hostname. And site1.com is one of my websites.
The sites are enabled by using the command `sudo a2ensite site1.com.conf`

My Apache `VirtualHost` file in `/var/www/site1.com/` look like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName  site1.com
        ServerAlias www.site1.com
        ServerAdmin myemail
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.com/web
        ErrorLog     /var/www/site1.com/logs/error.log
        CustomLog    /var/www/site1.com/logs/access.log combined
        <Directory "/var/www/site1.com/web">
                AllowOverride All
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using port 8080 because of Varnish.

The problem is when I try to configure a second domain. I've configure the VirtualHost exactly like the first one, changing the path to the files.

I don't know how to configure `/etc/hosts` to add the new domain, I've tried to configre adding a the second domain next to the first, but doesn't work.

```
127.0.1.1 site1.com site2.com
```

If I change the 127.0.1.1 with my server static IP, doesn't work neither.

```
mystaticip site1.com site2.com
```

I need help.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The following host file does the trick for me:

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1               localhost                       servername.yourdomain.com
# A.B.C.D stands for your IPv4 address
A.B.C.D                 servername.yourdomain.com       servername

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: And how can i deploy a second domain name?

Comment: That's what DNS does for you. It points all your domain names to one IP address. Your Apache configuration sends each domain name to its respective directory.